# Minimizing noise with single-ended opamps

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, differential-amplifier, negative-feedback, single-ended

Opamps often get used with one input at a DC voltage, usually the main ground per the [standard inverting amplifier example](https://www.circuitstoday.com/inverting-amplifier-using-opamp):
[image: inverting opamp application]

For low noise, a BJT input stage like [OPA1611](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa1612.pdf)'s is often chosen for the opamp:
[image: OPA1611 schematic]

But, this then causes flicker noise (I am concerned mainly about low frequencies near 1 Hz) on top of the "ground reference" due to the IN+ NPN transistor, so it seems that total noise could be reduced to half (or 0.707) if the IC were designed knowing that IN+ was always at a DC voltage.  Basically, I would rather see an opamp pinout with 1 input pin and 3 supplies than see an opamp pinout with 2 input pins and 2 supplies.

So, why can't I find low noise "single-ended amplifiers" instead of these "differential amplifiers"?  Does there exist a single-ended BJT amplifier for low noise at low frequencies?

Am I missing something or is the noise just sacrificed to allow more usage applications?

Comment: Are you aware of chopper-stabilized or auto-zero amps?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the chopping noise even though it is at higher frequencies.  I would like everything sitting nicely at DC voltages while it awaits a transient input.

Comment: And, even if I allowed chopping, I think the IC designers could still reduce the noise by half (or 0.707) if they knew IN+ was always grounded.

Comment: Autozero generally do not have chopping noise, hence the distinction. || If they knew one input were always grounded, *it wouldn't be a differential amplifier!* You would need to be shopping for a different type of amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

Low noise single-ended amplifiers often go by the name **pre-amplifier** in the low-frequency world. The www holds many rabbit holes worth of literature.

They are usually just used as another amplification stage in front of op-amps. Their voltage gain makes the noise of the op-amp almost meaningless.

Typical voltage noise values can be way below 1 nV/rtHz, but if you are after particularly low 1/f noise, some cherry picking might be required.

For low noise at frequencies well below 1 Hz forget about anything without modulation. The easiest way to have 1/f rejecting modulation is via zero-drift aka chopper-stabilized op-amps.

Comment: I don't find any "bjt preamplifier" ICs on a quick Google search.  In case you have an example part number (with no chopper), please add it to your answer since I still feel like ICs for precision applications always use differential inputs.

Comment: @bobuhito I think there are no ICs because usually you use a single transistor and 1 or 2 resistors for this. This isn't going to be linear. But if you want linearity, you will need that second transistor again anyway which brings you back to op-amps.

Answer (score 0):

> So, why can't I find low noise "single-ended amplifiers" instead of
> these "differential amplifiers"? Does there exist a single-ended BJT
> amplifier for low noise at low frequencies?

Look for chopper amplifiers. they specifically rectify the flicker noise to a higher frequency and then filter it out, then construct the DC signal again.